# Draw multiple SVG on one stage and export to single SVG (React)

Tags: konvajs

I'm using the react-konva package and would like to draw multiple SVG files on one stage with multiple layers and export all of them to one single SVG file.

I could only find the "Path" component which didn't accept my SVG files. How can I fix that?

And is there any way to export the whole stage to one SVG file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display SVG on canvas you should read [SVG on Canvas with Konva Tutorial](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/SVG_On_Canvas.html).

Konva **doesn't** support exporting into SVG format. If you want to export into SVG, you may need to write your own export tool. The tool should read the structure of your canvas scene and generate similar SVG output.